# How to cwd with nvim-adp-ui when starting debug

Tags: debugging, neovim

I am used to gdb and I wanted to move to nvim-adp-ui has it looks nicer.
However, with gdb i can change the working directory before 'run'
usually I worki like this:

```
file $(path/to/executable)/a.out
cd $(path/to/working/dir)
run
```

In nvim I start vim-adp-ui and it asked me for excutable path then start running. has I didn't set the working directory my program exist with error as it can't find the files required.
I've been looking for a wait to set cwd looks like I need to do it in the config file I am not sure about it but if it is the case I am more lost as I need to change the working directory per program.